# Security Across Domains with Web API Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application that makes calls to 100+ servers on our networks. Some of those servers are in domain1, some are in domain2, and others are in domain3. For example: serverA.domain1, or serverB.domain2.

This is the code that gets the services on a user-selected server:

```
var services = ServiceController.GetServices(serverNameWithSuffix)
    .Where(x => x.ServiceName.StartsWith(serviceStartsWith))
    .OrderBy(x => x.ServiceName);
```

When the Web API app was running as the default ApplicationPoolIdentity, there were permissions issues. So I changed the app pool to run under a service account. The app then works for everything in one domain, but not the other two. If I run the app pool as my user, everything works.

What's the standard for something like this? Do I need to have a service account created that has access to all servers on all domains, then make that account an admin on every server?

Comment: Thanks to the folks that have provided some guidance, but I've found what I needed to do. After I detect the domain in which the server lives, I'm going to run the code under the appropriate impersonated account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a sysadmin but my sysadmins have enabled me to do this with service accounts that IIS app pools run under. I believe the issue may be your service account's Group scope. Changing it to Global or Universal may fix your problem. Most likely your personal user account is already part of a security group with Global or Universal scope, and that would explain why running it under your credentials works.

[image: Group scope]